# How to get the strings from a file and store in a 2D char array and compare that 2D char array with a string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc, multidimensional-array

I have a text file, it has values(I usually call them as upc_values) of

```
01080006210
69685932764
40000114485
40000114724
07410855329
72908100004
66484101000
04000049163
43701256600
99999909001
07726009493
78732510053
78732510063
78732510073
78732510093
02842010109
02842010132
78732510213
02410011035
73999911110
```

```
 char *UPC_val = "99999909001";
 char upcbuf[100][12];
 char buf[12];

 memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
 memset(upcbuf,0,sizeof(upcbuf));
```

When I tried to fgets, I stored that in a 2D buffer.

```
 while ( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL ) {
        strncpy(upcbuf[i], buf, 11);
        i++;
 }
```

I tried to print the data in the buffer.

```
 puts(upcbuf[0]);
```

upcbuf[0] has the whole data in a continues stream,

0108000621069685932764400001144854000011472407410855329729081000046648410100004000049163437012566009999990900107726009493787325100537873251006378732510073787325100930284201010902842010132787325102130241001103573999911110

and I want to compare this upc values(11 digit) with another string(11 digit). I used,

```
 if(strncmp(UPC_Val,upcbuf[i],11) == 0)
 {
      //do stuff here
 }
```

It didn't work properly, I used strstr() too like,

```
 if(strstr(upcbuf[0],UPC_val) != NULL)
 {
     //do stuff here
 }
```

I am totally unaware of what it is doing, am I doing the comparison properly?
How to do this, any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't understand what are you trying to do here...

Comment: I have to compare the data in upcbuf with UPC_val, but I am not able to compare.

Comment: `char buf[12];` --> too small to read a line of 11 digits and `'\n'` into a _string_.  Use `char buf[12+1];`

Comment: here the problem is, why upcbuf[0] prints the whole buffer(continuous stream of upc vallues) I cant understand. @xing

Comment: `upcbuf[0]` is not a _string_.  `puts(upcbuf[0]);` expects a _string_.  `upcbuf[0]` is a character array lacking a null character - thus it is not a _string_.

Comment: where should I add upcbuf[i][11] = '\0'; in while loop, or out of the loop?? @xing

Comment: Thank you @xing I forgot the termination. I got the expected output. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

To read a line of text of 11 digits and a `'\n'` into a *string* needs an array of at least 13 to store the *string*.  There is little reason to be so tight.  Suggest 2x expected max size

```
char upcbuf[100][12];  // large enough for 100 * (11 digits and a \0)
...
#define BUF_SIZE (13*2)
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
while (i < 100 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) != NULL ) {
```

Lop off the potential tailing `'\n`'

```
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = '\0';
```

Check length and handle that somehow.

```
  if (len != 11) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Save/print the data

```
    // strncpy(upcbuf[i], buf, 11);  // fails to insure a null character at the end
    strcpy(upcbuf[i], buf);
    i++;
    puts(upcbuf[i]);
```

To compare strings

```
    if(strcmp(UPC_Val,upcbuf[i]) == 0) { 
      // strings match
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having trouble getting the logic to work after @chux's answer, then here is a short example implementing his suggestions that takes the filename to read as the first argument, and optionally the upc to search for as the second argument (it will search for `"99999909001"` by default [and it that case you can just read the file in on `stdin`]).

Note the use of an `enum` to define global constants for your row and column values. (you can use independent `#define ROW 128` and `#define COL 32` if you like) If you need constants in your code, define them once, at the top, so if they ever need to change, you have a single convenient place to change the values, rather than having to pick through your code, or perform a global search/replace to change them.

For example, you could put the logic together as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { COL = 32, ROW = 128 };   /* an enum is convenient for constants */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[COL] = "",             /* buffer to read each line    */
        upcbuf[ROW][COL] = { "" },  /* 2D array of ROW x COL chars */
        *upcval = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "99999909001";
    size_t n = 0;   /* index/counter */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;    /* file */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* fill upcbuf (you could search at same time, but let's fill) */
    while (n < ROW && fgets (buf, COL, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* get length          */
        /* test last char '\n', overwrite w/nul-terminating char   */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')
            buf[--len] = 0;
        strcpy (upcbuf[n++], buf);          /* copy to upcbuf      */
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    /* step through upcbuf - search for upcval */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (strcmp (upcbuf[i], upcval) == 0) {
            printf ("upcval: '%s' found at line '%zu'.\n", upcval, i + 1);
            return 0;
        }

    printf ("upcval: '%s' not found in file.\n", upcval);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/upcbuf dat/upcfile.txt
upcval: '99999909001' found at line '10'.

$ ./bin/upcbuf dat/upcfile.txt 01080006210
upcval: '01080006210' found at line '1'.

$ ./bin/upcbuf dat/upcfile.txt 02410011035
upcval: '02410011035' found at line '19'.

$ ./bin/upcbuf dat/upcfile.txt "not there!"
upcval: 'not there!' not found in file.
```

Also note that if you were simply searching for a single upc, then you could combine read and search in a single loop, but since you often read as a separate function, and then operate on the data elsewhere in your code, this example simply reads all upc values from the file into your array, and then searches though the array in a separate loop. Look things over, look at all answers, and let us know if you have any further questions.

As a final note, you have checked if the last char is `'\n'`, but what happens if it isn't? You should check if the length is `COL-1` indicating that additional characters remain unread in that line and handle the error (or just read and discard the remaining chars). You can do that with an addition similar to the following:

```
    /* test last char '\n', overwrite w/nul-terminating char   */
    if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')
        buf[--len] = 0;
    else if (len == COL - 1) {  /* if no '\n' & len == COL - 1 */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: line excces %d chars.\n", COL - 1);
        return 1;
    }
```

And, you need to use the `else if` and check the `COL - 1` and not simply use an `else` there because you may be reading from a file that does not have a *POSIX end-of-line* (e.g. a new-line character) after the final line of the file. `fgets` properly reads the final line, even without a POSIX line ending, but there will be no `'\n'` in `buf`. So even without the POSIX line ending, the line can be a valid line, and you are guaranteed to have a complete read, so long as the number of characters read (+ the *nul-terminating* char) does not equal your buffer size.

Comment: Chuckling... I got you beat there... My self-taught typing skills are suspect `:)`