# What is the meaning/logic of if(len ....) in the following bit of code?

Tags: c, strlen

This is from chux's answer to the question here: [How to get the strings from a file and store in a 2D char array and compare that 2D char array with a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889540/how-to-get-the-strings-from-a-file-and-store-in-a-2d-char-array-and-compare-that)

> Lop off the potential tailing '\n'
>
> ```
> size_t len = strlen(buf);
>   if (len && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = '\0';
> ```

I understand the second part of the if statement (checking if buf[len-1] == '\n'), but don't think I understand the if (len) part of it... Is it simply checking if there's actually a non-zero length to whatever's in the buffer (and if so, how can a situation where strlen returns 0 arise?) or is it something else?

Comment: `if (len)` is a lazy way of writing `if (len != 0)`.  The point of that is that if `len` is zero, you do not want to mess with `buf[len - 1]` (because `len` is an unsigned type, so `len - 1` wraps to a huge offset, out of bounds of the array).

Comment: The file could simply be empty (empty string in buffer), then Len-1 would become a really big number (underfloow as Len is unsigned)

Comment: @MrTux Had the file been empty, then `fgets()` would return `NULL` and the `buf[]` contents remain unchanged (uninitialized) in [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889789/2410359) and `strlen(buf)` not encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (i < 100 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) != NULL ) {
  // Lop off the potential tailing '\n'
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = '\0';
```

> Is it simply checking if there's actually a non-zero length to whatever's in the buffer

Yes.

Code is testing `len != 0` before attempting `buf[len-1]` to prevent accessing `buf[]` out of range.
[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962064/what-is-the-meaning-logic-of-iflen-in-the-following-bit-of-code/52968751#comment92830849_52962064)

---

> (and if so, how can a situation where strlen returns 0 arise?)

Defensive coding: The *line* read may start with a *null character*.

The prior code has `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)` which reads a *line* and then forms a *string*.  In the C standard library<sup>1</sup>, a *line* of input is the characters up to and including a `'\n'`.  The *null character* has no special significance on input, it is just like another other character.  After a *line* is read with `fgets()` and saved in `buf[]`, a *null character* is appended.  `size_t len = strlen(buf);` return the length based on  the first *null character*, not necessarily the appended one.

If the text file line is

```
'\0', 'a', 'b', 'c', '\n'
```

Then `fgets(buf, ...)` will result in `buf[]` as

```
'\0', 'a', 'b', 'c', '\n', '\0'
```

And `len == 0`.

ASCII text files uncommonly contain *null characters*.  Their presence is usually a mistake or nefarious (a hacker exploit).  *Null characters* are common in UTF-16 text files, yet reading such a file with the code in question has other troubles too.

---

<sup>1</sup> "A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined." C11dr §7.21.2 2

Answer (score 2):

An empty string has `0` length.

The following code will result in `len` being `0`:

```
const char * str = "";
size_t len = strlen(str);
```

So we must check it before accessing `str[len-1]` to avoid an integer wraparound.

Note that the length of the buffer which holds `str` is `1`, because of the trailing `'\0'`, so the memory will look like this:

```
buf --> [ '\0' ]
```

Comment: It is wraparound rather than, or as much as, underflow because `size_t` is an unsigned integer type.  C11 [§6.2.5 Types ¶9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9): … _A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type._

Answer (score 2):

You can index an array only when something is greater than zero. So to access `buff[len-1]` `len` must be greater than zero otherwise if len is zero then `len - 1` will be a very large number defined by `SIZE_MAX` and buff[-1] is an error.
The statement `if (len && buff[len-1]=='\n')` combines two conditions:
First checks for `len > 0` and then the `buff[len-1] == '\n'`.
The above given `if` statement simply means the following:
`if( (len > 0)  && (buff[len-1] == '\n'))`

Comment: `len` is a `size_t` value (which is an `unsigned` integer type), so if `len` is zero, `len - 1` will not be -1, but `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of sizeof , alignof (since C11) and offsetof, depending on the data model.
```

I think you are right in terms of checking. size_t is the unsigned integer type, so it is checking that condition in order to proceed with the other check and `buf[--len]`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t